# How to make an IF statement remain true throughout an INDEX MATCH in Excel 2010+?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to use an INDEX MATCH to return the optimal choice from a list of items associated to values that change based on various criteria. My current sheet setup and formula is this:

```
A     B    C
Item1 Bad  27
Item2 Good 15
Item3 Good 27
Item4 Bad  44
```

Column A is a named range `Item`.
Column B is a named range `ItemType`.
Column C is a named range `ItemValue`

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")),MATCH(MAX(IF(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")&"Type")="Good",INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")&"Value"))),INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")&"Value"),0))
```

(entered as an array formula)
In its current iteration, this will return `Item1`. I would like it to return `Item3`.

In this example, `'Sheet'!B3` contains the category to search (in this example `Item`). I use a variety of named ranges based on the data in that cell and suffixes with the use of INDIRECT/SUBSTITUTE. My current formula finds the highest value that also is `Good`, but then returns the first value that matches it, regardless of it being `Good` or `Bad`. I have tried adding an additional IF statement at different points of the formula but the cell would either return `FALSE` or a formula syntax error. How can I maintain my `="Good"` IF statement throughout the formula?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you are going to get an answer. Please provide a snapshot of the data you have in `sheet` and what you would like the solution to be based on the sampled data you provided.

Comment: @dimitris_ps The only data relevant to the formula in `sheet` is cell `B3`, which contains `Item` in order to point the indirect substitutes to the correct named ranges. The named ranges are in a separate `source` sheet. As I mentioned, I would like the solution to be `Item3` in this case, as this is the highest value in Column C/`ItemValue` that is also `Good` in Column B/`ItemType`. Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to double up the *Good* condition. Once for determining the max number and then again with the max number to determine the Item.

This non-array equivalent is the syntax I favor over the array method.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")), MAX(INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")))*(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")&"Type")="Good")*(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")&"Value")=MAX(INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")&"Value")*(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet'!B3," ","")&"Type")="Good"), , ))), , )))
```

This is your array method.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3), MATCH(MAX(IF(INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3&"Type")="Good",INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3&"Value"))), IF(INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3&"Type")="Good", INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3&"Value")), 0))
```

If the *___Type* and *___Value* are always in the same position relative to the primary, you might want to abandon the three named ranges and just use a single named range with `OFFSET`.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3), MATCH(MAX(IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3), 0, 1)="Good",OFFSET(INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3), 0, 2))), IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3), 0, 1)="Good", OFFSET(INDIRECT('Sheet'!B3), 0, 2)), 0))
```

The [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) is considered a *volatile function*. These recalculate whenever anything in the workbook changes and should be avoided for that reason. However, you are already using the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) and that is considered volatile as well.

Comment: I was able to achieve the expected result with the array method and I'll try switching to `OFFSET` and see how that goes. Thank you very much!